# Proof of inequalities using MVT, when f(c) is infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that for $0<x<1$,

> $1≤ \frac {e^x-1}{x} ≤ \frac{1}{1-x}$

I've tried using the MVT on the interval, but one of the terms always tends to 0.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Can you prove that $e^x\ge1+x$ for all real $x$? Both of your inequalities follow from this.

Comment: This inequality has been used in previous questions, so we can assume this

Comment: Since you are restricted to the interval $0 < x <1$, you can proceed in the following steps: write down the series expansion of $e^x$, and use the fact that $x>0$ for getting the lower bound and the fact that $x<1$ to get the upper bound.

Comment: Try manipulating $e^x\ge1+x$ in some ways and it shouldn't be too hard to achieve your desired inequalities (for the second one, try to consider $-x$ instead of $x$).

Comment: @panini, so the expansion for $e^x$ =1 when x tends to 0, and e when x tends to 1, but when you sub this back in the same problem exists in that you get (1-1)/x and this tends to infinity as x tends to 0?

Comment: Yes, the expression $\frac{e^x - 1}{x}$ is not defined exactly at the point $x=0$. This is the reason your problem considers the open interval $(0,1)$ and not $[0,1]$. However, for $x$ very small but not equal to $0$, you can have the required inequalities.  Write $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} \dots$. Then for any $x>0$, you have $\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1 + x/2 + x^2/6 + \dots$. Now you can use the fact that $0<x<1$ to get your inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

$e^x-1=e^c(x)$ where $c\in [0,x]$, we deduce that ${e^x\over x}>1$, we have $e^c\leq e^x$.

$x\leq -ln(1-x)$ if $x\in [0,1)$. To see this, let   $g(x)=x+ln(1-x)$, $g'(x)=1-{1\over{1-x}}<0$ on $[0,1)$ so $g$ decreases on $[0,1)$ and $g(x)\leq g(0)=0$.
This implies that $e^c\leq e^x\leq e^{-ln(1-x)}={1\over{1-x}}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that
$$ \frac{e^x-1}{x}\ge1. $$
Note that
$$ \frac{e^x-1}{x}\le \frac{1}{1-x} $$
is equivalent to
$$ (1-x)(e^x-1)\le x.$$
Let $f(x)=(1-x)(e^x-1)$ and then $f'(x)=1-xe^x<1$. Applying the MVT in $[0,x]$ for $x\in(0,1)$, one has
$$ (1-x)(e^x-1)=f'(c)x\le x. $$